# "Object required" error VBA

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I've got a Worksheet titled "Survey". I'm trying to attach checkboxes to all of the cells in column A that are next to answers, and for some reason I'm getting an "object required" error. The 4 lines near the beginning, starting with "Set rng =", are highlighted.

I'm pretty new to VBA, so I'm not sure if this is just a simple syntax issue that I'm not seeing. I've tried searching for the proper format, to no avail. Can anyone help? Here's the code that I've got:

```
Sub AddCheckBox()

Dim rng As Range
Dim rcell As Range

Set rng = Survey.Range("A7:A10,A13:A17,A21:A25,A28:A33" _
& "A36:A43, A48,A51:A56,A60:A66,A69:A73,A76:A80" _
& "A83:A87, A90:A94, A97:A102, A105:A113, A116:A122, A125:A131" _
& "A134:A141,A145:A149, A152:A158, A161:A165")



DelCheckBox 

For Each rcell In rng
  With ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Add(rcell.Left, _
     rcell.Top, rcell.Width, rcell.Height)
     .LinkedCell = rcell.Offset(, 0).Address(External:=True)
     .Interior.ColorIndex = 14   'or  xlNone or xlAutomatic
     .Caption = ""
     .Border.Weight = xlThin
  End With
Next

With Range("A7:A10,A13:A17,A21:A25,A28:A33" _
& "A36:A43, A48,A51:A56,A60:A66,A69:A73,A76:A80" _
& "A83:A87, A90:A94, A97:A102, A105:A113, A116:A122, A125:A131" _
& "A134:A141,A145:A149, A152:A158, A161:A165")
.Rows.RowHeight = 15
End With
End Sub


Sub DelCheckBox()
For Each cell In Range("A1:A166")
    Worksheets("Survey").CheckBoxes.Delete
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the commas at the end of your lines.  Try this:

```
Set rng = Survey.Range("A7:A10,A13:A17,A21:A25,A28:A33," _
& "A36:A43, A48,A51:A56,A60:A66,A69:A73,A76:A80," _
& "A83:A87, A90:A94, A97:A102, A105:A113, A116:A122, A125:A131," _
& "A134:A141,A145:A149, A152:A158, A161:A165")
```

Note, you'll have to make the same change where you have the With Range("....") block as well.  Also, the above code does not reflect the validity of the rest of what you're trying to do...just that one error.

*EDIT to fix issues down the road...*

Try this all of this code and see if it does what you're after:

```
 Sub test()

Dim rng As Range
Dim rcell As Range

Set rng = Sheets("Survey").Range("A7:A10,A13:A17,A21:A25,A28:A33," _
& "A36:A43, A48,A51:A56,A60:A66,A69:A73,A76:A80," _
& "A83:A87, A90:A94, A97:A102, A105:A113, A116:A122, A125:A131," _
& "A134:A141,A145:A149, A152:A158, A161:A165")

DelCheckBox

For Each rcell In rng
  With Sheets("Survey").CheckBoxes.Add(rcell.Left, _
     rcell.Top, rcell.Width, rcell.Height)
     .LinkedCell = rcell.Offset(, 0).Address(External:=True)
     .Interior.ColorIndex = 14   'or  xlNone or xlAutomatic
     .Caption = ""
     .Border.Weight = xlThin
  End With
Next

rng.Rows.RowHeight = 15
End Sub
Sub DelCheckBox()

Sheets("Survey").DrawingObjects.Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: why set rng and then not use it in the `with` statement? could easily be one line: `survey.rng.rows.rowheight = 15`

Comment: @scott because I just quickly corrected the other issues in the code.  Didn't really rewrite the whole thing.  It's been corrected now...

Comment: I'm still getting the Run-time error '424 Object required after copy/pasting your code into a new module.

Comment: Then you're doing it wrong :)   Is the sheet named "Survey" (like the actual tab name) or did you go in to the IDE and change the codename of your sheet to Survey?

Comment: The tab name is "Survey". EDIT: clarification

Comment: @AndyArdueser  Got it.  Amended code to work on a tab named "Survey".  Give it a whirl and see if it works.  It is on my test workbook.

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you so much. So it was just the addition of Sheets("...")?

Comment: Just a suggestion but this range is, I think, dangerously close to the maximum character limit that can contain in a Range.Address string (255 characters).   If you make it any bigger, you'll likely get a truncated range address, and as a result, your code will appear to not work as expected.  Might consider redefining the range and using some logic to determine which rows/cells to skip, rather than trying to hard-code each cell/area in the range address.

Comment: @AndyArdueser  Glad I could help!  Feel free to mark it as the 'accepted' answer if it solves your issue.  To answer your question, no there was more to it than that.  There was the commas at the end of your range statement. Also, the way you were deleting the checkbox objects in the DelCheckBox was wrong.  Also, you should heed David's comments as well as it could nip some headaches in the bud should your sheet get any more complex.